# Leverage browser caching using htaccess not working for some images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I try to fix leverage browser caching for my website using htaccess like this:

```
# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 secondsr"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

but everytime PageSpeed Insights always gives me a result that some of my images needs to be cache by using leverage browser caching:

[image]

i already make sure my mod_expires is active and i already install pagespeed module for my apache server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all images that Google Pagespeed Insights say need to be cached are PNGs. The line in your .htaccess file for PNGs has a typo - you wrote 'secondsr' instead of 'seconds'. Try to fix this and see if it helps :)

Line 8:
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 secondsr"

Change to:
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"

I'm having a similar issue though, in that two or my resources are still coming up on Pagespeed Insights as not being cached even though in their response headers it says they are, so not sure if this will solve your problem but worth a shot and it is something that needs to be fixed anyway.